# Как установить картинку на фон сайта?

Tags: css

Я вот решил установить картинку на фон, и делаю вот так:

```
body{
    background-image: url (<img src=img/1252508063_8679789_8235865_7148521_2068748_1053759_371970_268.gif);
}
```

Но у меня не картинка, а белый фон. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Comment: Есть такая программа Dremweaver называется. И нет проблем с адресом картинки... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так?

```
body{
background-image: url(img/1252508063_8679789_8235865_7148521_2068748_1053759_371970_268.gif);
}
```

**UPD:** ха, прикол, сразу не сообразил. Пробел уберите url[без пробела](

> нужно url( вместо url (

Comment: Так тоже пробовал =)

Comment: Ну если и так не работает, то проверьте наличие картинки на сервере.

Comment: Значит нужно проверить путь до картинки.
Если (img/1252508063_8679789_8235865_7148521_2068748_1053759_371970_268.gif), то картинка должна лежать в соседней папке с вашей страницей. А если (/img/1252508063_8679789_8235865_7148521_2068748_1053759_371970_268.gif), то папка с картинкой должна быть в корне сайта (http://site/img/1252508063_8679789_8235865_7148521_2068748_1053759_371970_268.gif).
А еще лучше было бы дать ссылку на Вашу страницу.

Comment: Надо проверить путь к фоновой картинке относительно страницы (если стиль определяется в тэге style) или подключаемого в тэге link css-файла.

IE может блокировать загрузку фоновых картинок, если файл хостится не на сервере, а в файловой системе.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, уже выше написал про относительные пути. А во-вторых, img/1252508063_8679789_8235865_7148521_2068748_1053759_371970_268.gif- ну вряд ли это путь в файловой системе.